# Use mount to access a "proc" folder with my user

Tags: linux, mount, kernel, proc

Is it possible to use mount to access a "proc" folder with my user?

Hypothetical example:

```
mount -t proc -o umask=0022,gid=<MY_GID>,uid=<MY_UID> /proc/<MY_PID>/root /home/<MY_USER>/<SOME_FOLDER>
```

**NOTE:** I tried several and several approaches, but without success. bindfs also does not work.

Thanks! =D

Comment: have a look at [this]  (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133922/what-causes-proc-pid-resources-to-become-owned-by-root-despite-the-procs-b?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) . question and answer

Comment: In "man proc" you can see the mount options for the proc filesystem. The mount options you mention are NOT filesystem-independent (see "man mount").